Intellij IDEA console logs output lines are reduced in one project window, but full in another
I have two projects open in one Intellij IDEA window each and during tests or run the logs for one project window are like so:
2024-09-11 07:35:02.892  INFO 47728 --- [main] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : Job: [FlowJob: [name=JOB_KCRM_c92f8ec1-9000-45c2-86bf-b200f264d6c0]] launched with the following parameters: [{run.id=1}]
2024-09-11 07:35:02.898  INFO 47728 --- [main] o.s.c.t.b.l.TaskBatchExecutionListener   : The job execution id 873 was run within the task execution 3167
2024-09-11 07:35:02.921  INFO 47728 --- [main] o.s.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler     : Executing step: [startTasklet]
2024-09-11 07:35:03.403  INFO 47728 --- [main] o.s.batch.core.step.AbstractStep         : Step: [startTasklet] executed in 482ms
2024-09-11 07:35:03.414  INFO 47728 --- [main] o.s.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler     : Executing step: [errorTasklet]
2024-09-11 07:35:03.675  INFO 47728 --- [main] o.s.batch.core.step.AbstractStep         : Step: [errorTasklet] executed in 261ms
2024-09-11 07:35:03.679  INFO 47728 --- [main] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : Job: [FlowJob: [name=JOB_KCRM_c92f8ec1-9000-45c2-86bf-b200f264d6c0]] completed with the following parameters: [{run.id=1}] and the following status: [COMPLETED] in 785ms

And then in another project window it's like so:
Job: [FlowJob: [name=JOB_KCRM_c92f8ec1-9000-45c2-86bf-b200f264d6c0]] launched with the following parameters: [{run.id=1}]
The job execution id 873 was run within the task execution 3167
Executing step: [startTasklet]
Step: [startTasklet] executed in 482ms
Executing step: [errorTasklet]
Step: [errorTasklet] executed in 261ms
Job: [FlowJob: [name=JOB_KCRM_c92f8ec1-9000-45c2-86bf-b200f264d6c0]] completed with the following parameters: [{run.id=1}] and the following status: [COMPLETED] in 785ms

I must have done something by mistake to change it, but I don't remember what or when or where I did this.
Neither of the two projects have a logback.xml or log4j2.xml file or similar and in application.yml both projects have set the logging.level.root=INFO and this was like this from the beggining before the logs output format changed.
This happens for all repos in the project window with the reduced logs output, not just one in particular. And in the other window, the logs output are complete for all repos.
Any help in restoring the logs will be appreciated!
Thank you very much!
EDIT: The fix in my case was navigating to External Libraries, finding org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.30, right click Open Library Settings and changing slf4j-api-1.7.30.jar to slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar
